# VSCode linux build multiple cpu's g++

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, build, g++

Is it possible to use VSCode, linux, g++ to compile program using multiple CPU cores to speed up build? I mean it can compile multiple .cpp files at once to speed it up as Visual Studio does.

Comment: use a build tool (Make, CMake) and add the parallel make argument (`-j n`)

Comment: Well of course, that is the solution! I have altered my tasks.json:
        {
            "label": "my build",
            "group": "build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "make",
            "args": ["build", "--jobs=6"],
            "problemMatcher": "$gcc"
        },

Comment: Interesting experience was, that just adding '-j' took too much of my CPU's - all my memory and CPU was taken and PC was blocked for few minutes.

Comment: with `-j` it allocates a few compile tasks per available CPU, result no time slice left for the window manager and mouse looks dead, if the CPU is hyper threaded the impact is worse